# Proof of Theorem 22.5 in Matsumura's Commutative ring theory

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Theorem 22.5. Let $(A, \mathfrak{m}, k)$ and $\left(B, \mathfrak{n}, k^{\prime}\right)$ be Noetherian local rings, $f:A \longrightarrow B$ a local homomorphism, and $u: M \rightarrow N$ a morphism of finite $B$ -modules. Then if $N$ is flat over $A$, the following two conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $u$ is injective and $N / u(M)$ is flat over $A$;
> 2. $\bar{u}: M \otimes_{A} k \longrightarrow N \otimes_{A} k$ is injective.

In the book, the author says that 1 to 2 is trivial, however it seems not for me. What I had is as below.

Suppose (1) holds. Then we may think $M$ as a submodule of $N$. Moreover, since $k$ is a field, every element of $M \otimes_{A}k$ has a form $m \otimes 1$ for some $m \in M$. Then, if $\overline{u}(m \otimes 1)=0$ for some nonzero $m\otimes 1$, then $u(m)\otimes 1=0$ in $N \otimes_{A}k$, thus $u(m) = f(a)n$ for some $n \in N, a \in \mathfrak{m}$ but $m \not\in f(\mathfrak{m})M$. Since $M$ is a submodule of $N$, $u(m)=m$, thus $m \in f(\mathfrak{m})N$ but not $f(\mathfrak{m})M$. Therefore, the map $N \xrightarrow{f(a)} N$ induces non-injective map $N/M \xrightarrow{f(a)} N/M$. Since $N/M$ is flat, and $f(a) \cdot (n+M)=0$, thus Theorem 7.6 of the same book implies that there exists an integer $s$ and $b_{k} \in A, (n_{k} +M)\in N/M$ such that $f(a)b_{k}=0$ for all $k$ and $(n+M) = b_{k}(n_{k} +M)$ for all $k$. In other words, $m = f(a)b_{k}n_{k}+m'$ for some $m' \in M$. Then, $f(a)(n-b_{k}n_{k})=m' \in M$, hence $m' \otimes 1 =0$ in $N \otimes_{A} k$.

However, this argument cannot show that actually $n$ is came from $N$; could you give me hint for showing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (1) implies (2), I don't think you need to work quite so hard. Assuming (1), you have a short exact sequence of $B$-modules
$$0 \rightarrow M \xrightarrow{u} N \rightarrow N/u(M) \rightarrow 0.$$

Tensoring over $A$ with $k$ and using that $N/u(M)$ is flat over $A$ gives a short exact sequence
$$0 \rightarrow M \otimes_A k \xrightarrow{\bar{u}} N \otimes_A k \rightarrow N/u(M) \otimes_A k \rightarrow 0$$
and thus we have $(2)$.

Comment: Oh, I thought it in a difficult way. Thank you very much!